# Как обработать команду бота с эмоджи в тексте? C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

При нажатии на KeyboardButton отправляется сообщение с эмоджи в чат, как мне обработать данное сообщение в конструкции switch case.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: копируй эмоджи из телеги и сравнивай как строки, в js у меня работало, думаю и тут сработает https://github.com/AntonNikolaevmyname/Telegram-Smile-Bot

Comment: Скинь пример кода, а то я не могу открыть твой файлы)Пожалуйста

Comment: вот здесь тебе надо 2 файлика: index.js с кодом и collections.js в нем хранится коллекция эмоджи смайлов https://github.com/AntonNikolaevmyname/Telegram-Smile-Bot/tree/master/tg-bot-nodejs/Server

Comment: Какой не очень подход, может есть ещё идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Долго я думал над этой проблемой, но всё же нашёл решение. Берёте текст сообщения из ТГ вместе с эмоджи, и кидаете в обработчик команд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не все эмоджи читаются, как это было у меня